# connection refused: no further information phpstorm

Tags: php, битрикс, phpstorm, centos7

поставил битрикс вм на сервер CentOS 7 , запустился,  сайт работает,конект через winSCP по sftp работает, в пхп шторме при создании проекта  тест конект ок при подключении по SFTP, но дальше вот это на скрине,в чем проблема? [скрин](https://i.imgur.com/HDPACZq.png)